# Can I use SSRS 2016 with SQL Server 2008 R2 database engine?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I don't know that much about the state of products offering reporting/analytics, but I first got into OLAP in the late 90s, with a data warehousing tool, but then didn't touch it again for a while.  ***My vocabulary on the topic may not be precise.***

I have data in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  The application putting data into it is not certified for SQL 2016, but SSRS 2016 (SQL Server Reporting Services 2016) has caught my eye.  It seems to have the features I'd like to use with this application.  I am adding reporting capabilities to a 3rd party application.

Can I create a new machine with just SSRS 2016 (which is a feature of SQL Server as a whole) and point it to the SQL 2008 R2 server with the database such that I can then start doing reporting on the application database?

What are the ramifications if the SQL 2008 R2 server is also an Enterprise server (or cluster) with many other databases on it?

This is not related to Sharepoint.  The 3rd party application is not a Microsoft application.

Comment: u mean to use report server pointing on older version of database ?

Comment: you can use SSRS and fetch data from older databases.

Comment: Do you mean use an older version to host the ReportServer databases, or to use as datasources?

Comment: I don't know much about SSRS, but I don't understand how you guys are getting confused.

Comment: Just asking for clarification because your question isn't clear.

Comment: To me, backend = ReportServer databases. MS say 'compatible' here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj714188.aspx but don't specify which versions are compatible. If you mean datasources, then absolutely, yes you can.

Comment: Also note that some *editions* of SSRS are limited to using other editions of SQL Server for their report server database. You can use any database you have a driver for as a report data source though

Comment: According to th SSRS archictecture, you are talking about SQL Server 2008R2 as data source. And SSRS 2016 supports varities of data sources including all versions of SQL Servers. Details are given in this documentation. [Reporting Services Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt742500.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SSRS 2016 and fetch data from another databases.

When you defines the connection string of data sources, you can use whatever of your installed drivers.

According to [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx):

**Built-in data extensions**

> Default data extensions in Reporting Services include the following types of data connections:
>
> Microsoft SQL Server
> Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
> Microsoft SharePoint List
> Azure SQL Database
> Microsoft SQL Server Parallel Data Warehouse
> OLE DB
> Oracle
> SAP NetWeaver BI
> Hyperion Essbase
> Teradata
> XML
> ODBC
>
> Microsoft BI Semantic Model for Power View: On a SharePoint site that has been configured for a Power Pivot gallery and Power View, this data source type is available. This data source type is used only for Power View presentations. For more information, see Building the Perfect BI Semantic Tabular Models for Power View.